# How to use data from the localstorage in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

How to use data from the localstorage for the another component. Localstorage in service are:

localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: success,res:res.data}));

I want to use id, username etc from the data in another component How it possible

Comment: `localStorage` isn't scoped to a component, it's a global object.

Comment: its available everywhere, just use it the same way as you did in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can retrieve current user from storage like

**create one function for get a current user in your user service and use it globally**

```
getCurrentUser(): void {
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add individual item to localstorage

To set item

```
    localStorage.setItem('username', 'ActualUserName');
```

To retrieve item

```
    let username= localStorage.getItem("username");
```

Comment: console.log value:                                                                                      
 Storage {currentUser: "{"username":"q","token":true,"res":{"id":2,"firstn…lephant.jpg","updated_at":"2017-07-05 10:21:23"}}", length: 1}
currentUser
:
"{"username":"q","token":true,"res":{"id":2,"firstname":"a","lastname":"a","username":"q","image_file":"elephant.jpg","updated_at":"2017-07-05 10:21:23"}}"

Comment: and I want to retrieve only firstname and id and res individually how it possible

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
    let currentUser = localStorage.getItem( 'currentUser' );
    this.token = JSON.parse( currentUser )['token'];
    this.username = JSON.parse( currentUser )['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    userid=  (this.currentUser.res.id);